# How to setup Eclipse for C/C++ in MAC

Tags: c, eclipse, macos, ide

> I am new to MAC OS, I am using MacBook pro. I want to setup and download eclipse for C/C++. please tell me how to do this. I have downloaded the eclipse from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/neon2 , I am getting this error when launching eclipse.

```
Process:               eclipse [698]
Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/*/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Identifier:            org.eclipse.eclipse
Version:               3.8 (3.8)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           eclipse [698]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-02-18 14:07:18.587 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12 (16A323)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        82A276A8-92E3-A0D6-B844-365149993D95

Sleep/Wake UUID:       F2C21C18-579C-4FCF-9BB7-D6F8273D8158

Time Awake Since Boot: 2000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       54 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000003c
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x3c:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100004000 [   16K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /var/folders/*/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa6c53fd4 CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName + 36
1   org.eclipse.eclipse             0x00000001000030bd findSymbol + 66
2   org.eclipse.eclipse             0x00000001000018be original_main + 1572
3   org.eclipse.eclipse             0x0000000100001f7d main + 1230
4   org.eclipse.eclipse             0x0000000100001158 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffbbdf04e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffbbed7632 _pthread_wqthread + 1023
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffbbed7221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffbbdf04e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffbbed77c5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffbbed7221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffbbdf04e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffbbed77c5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffbbed7221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00006080000204a0  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x6974696e49746573  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00006080000204a0  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbff9b0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbff580
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000600  r10: 0x0000000000000002  r11: 0x00007fffa6c53fb0
  r12: 0x00000001000043f8  r13: 0x00006080000a00c0  r14: 0x00006080000204a0  r15: 0x39d09da8b1ae0003
  rip: 0x00007fffa6c53fd4  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x000000000000003c

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
MALLOC                            31.4M       16 
MALLOC guard page                   32K        7 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        5 
Stack                             9752K        5 
VM_ALLOCATE                          8K        3 
__DATA                            18.8M      189 
__IMAGE                            528K        2 
__LINKEDIT                       111.3M        4 
__TEXT                           123.8M      193 
__UNICODE                          556K        2 
shared memory                      304K        6 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            352.5M      423 

Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B0D, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343235533643465236412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343235533643465236412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.10.1a16)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.0f18, 3 services, 17 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS545050A7E362, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS41N
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Comment: You can google this and you'll get thousands of answers

Comment: https://orfe.princeton.edu/help/article-294

Answer (score 2):

Try this [package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/heliossr2) of eclipse. In macOS High Sierra works fine. But the problem is gdb does not work well for the debugging in mac. 
An alternative IDE is CLION for C++ which is free for the students. You will have perfect debugger using LLDB. Note that you need to prepare Cmake if you use CLION.